# Joomla database how to do WHERE AND OR

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

I need to get the following mysql WHERE clause into a form usable with joomla database connection:

```
WHERE
hady9_session.session_id = 'acl7e1bn099rrlhkvsrhl13bu7' AND
(hady9_hikashop_product.product_parent_id = '5722' OR
'5412' OR
'5877' OR
'8357' OR
'8202')
```

So far I have:

```
->where('hady9_session.session_id = '. $db->quote($thesession));
```

How do I get the AND OR parts into it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work... let me know if it doesn't work.

```
->where($db->quoteName('hady9_session.session_id').' = '.$db->quote($thesession).'AND ('.$db->quoteName('hady9_hikashop_product.product_parent_id').' = '.$db->quote('5722').'OR'.$db->quote('5412').'OR'.$db->quote('5877').'OR'.$db->quote('8357').'OR'.$db->quote('8202').')');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
->where( $db->quoteName('hady9_session.session_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($thesession) . 
        'AND' . $db->quoteName('hady9_hikashop_product.product_parent_id')  . ' = ' . $db->quote('5722') .
        'OR' . $db->quote('5412') .
        'OR' . $db->quote('5877') .
        'OR' . $db->quote('8357') .
        'OR' . $db->quote('8202')
       );
```

Note that I have also wrapped your database columns inside `$db->quoteName()`

Hope this helps and let me know if it works or not

Comment: Done sorry I'm still a noob here.